# Autoupdate broken

Tags: bug

For a few days the autoupdate of [*Realtime questions*](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime) is broken for me.

Tested on Firefox and Chrome: both did not autoupdate questions.

Comment: And what does your JavaScript console say?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Chrome *Console* page in inspector shows no error.

Comment: I have the same problem on Firefox. The console shows two problems: _Firefox cannot connect to server ws://sockets-se.or.stackexchange.com/_ (translated because my Firefox speaks German) and _Error: useless setTimeout call (missing quotes around argument?)_

Comment: OK, found that in Chrome it's not working indeed while in IE9 it does work. IE9 send "live poll" every 15 seconds or so thus it works, however Chrome has web sockets thus I believe something there is broken, server side. Also worth to mention the real time update of the messages in the Collider is not working on Stack Exchange site.